# The project shows error while the components don't?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

The contents are not showing any error!! I don't understand what the problem is?[image]

Edit: I have already tried cleaning the projects, without success!
It's showing "failed to load properties file!

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: I close eclipse and delete `adb.exe` from PC processes everytime I get weird things there.

Comment: @Ashwyn:please add your project "log"

Comment: It's showing "failed to load properties file!

Comment: have you changed min/max/target sdk in manifest and not made the change in properties file

Answer (score 3):

You can use,

```
Window --> Show View --> Problems
```

and/or

```
Window --> Show View --> Error Log
```

Cleaning the project and restarting eclipse might help too.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the 'Problems' view in these cases in Eclipse. Window -> Show View -> Problems if it's not currently visible for you. Probably the java compiler version is wrong or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project. Sometimes this works fine for me.

- Project -> Clean

Use the Error log

- Window -> Show View -> Error Log